# How can I run a function when internet connection is established?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

The app is a quiz, and if user finishes the round he may send the points in firebase. If user is not connected to internet, I save the points in device memory, so when connection is established the points are send in firebase.

The best would be to let this happen automatically and show a message...
I'm trying to do this in `App.js` in a `useEffect`, but it checks only if I **refresh** the app. I tried `withNavigationFocus` and `useFocusEffect` but error: `the App.js is unable to get access to navigation...`.

I could also move the code to `WelcomeScreen.js` and show a button if connection is established to add the points, but it's not that user friendly.

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Thanks!

```js
useEffect(() => {

    const getPoints = async () => {
      let points = await AsyncStorage.getItem("savedPoints");
      if (!!points) {
        const getEmail = async () => {
          const userData = await AsyncStorage.getItem("userData");
          if (userData) {
            const transformedData = JSON.parse(userData);
            const { userEmail } = transformedData;
            return userEmail;
          }
        };
        const email = await getEmail();
        // Give it some time to get the token and userId,
        // because saveData needs them.
        setTimeout(
          async () => await dispatch(dataActions.saveData(email, +points)),
          3000
        );
        await AsyncStorage.removeItem("savedPoints");
      }
    };

    NetInfo.fetch().then(state => {
      if (state.isConnected) {
        console.log("isConnected");
        getPoints();
      }
    });
  }, []);
```

The solution

**WelcomeScreen.js**

```js
const [isConnected, setIsConnected] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("useEffect welcome");
    
    const unsub = NetInfo.addEventListener(state => {
      setIsConnected(state.isConnected);
    });
    
    return () => unsub();
  }, []);
  
  const getPoints = async () => {
    console.log("getPoints welcome");
    let points = await AsyncStorage.getItem("savedPoints");
    if (!!points) {
      const getEmail = async () => {
        const userData = await AsyncStorage.getItem("userData");
        if (userData) {
          // parse converts a string to an object or array
          const transformedData = JSON.parse(userData);
          const { userEmail } = transformedData;
          return userEmail;
        }
      };
      const email = await getEmail();
      // Give it some time to get the token and userId,
      // because saveData needs them.
      setTimeout(
        async () => await dispatch(dataActions.saveData(email, +points)),
        3000
      );
      await AsyncStorage.removeItem("savedPoints");
    }
  };

  if (isConnected) getPoints();
```

Comment: Firebase supports this feature and it's called Firebase Offline Capabilities.

Comment: Hey @realarb thanks for the comment. I will for sure check it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set up a listener to listen for an internet connection. Don't use any logic in app.js, use it in a separate screen component.

```js
constructor(props) {
  super(props);

  this.state = {
    isConnected: false
  };
}
componentDidMount() {
  this.listenForInternetConnection = NetInfo.addEventListener(state => {
    // your logic is here or setState   
    this.setState({
      isConnected: state.isConnected
    });
  });
}

componentWillUnmount() {
  this.listenForInternetConnection();
}
```

Comment: Amazing! I moved the code to WelcomeScreen.js and it works immediately as the connection is established.I will post the solution above.   Thanks a lot!

Answer (score -1):

You can use JS EventListeners

```
window.addEventListener('load', () => {

  navigator.onLine ? showStatus(true) : showStatus(false);

  window.addEventListener('online', () => {
    showStatus(true);
  });

  window.addEventListener('offline', () => {
    showStatus(false);
  });
});
```

Comment: you can't use "window" in react native, because it doesn't exist.